# Extracting Fan's List from Facebook page

Tags: list, facebook-page

I have to extract fan list from my Facebook fan page( I am the Admin of the page ) into an excel sheet, can it be done ?

I have tried other method available over but couldn't succeed.

PS: I am not a coding geek, please help me with some simple steps.

Ishant Jain

Answer (score 4):

Yes, type this into your browser bar

`https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id={pageid}`

Copy/paste the results into your spreadsheet.

Note: You can only get up to 500 of the latest fans from that link.
Note 2: There is no programmatic way to get that data. Many have tried.  Many have failed.

Comment: Web scrapping is always an option, isn't it?

Comment: It's the only documented way from Facebook to get at the users who've liked your page.

Comment: Out of 103 fans on my page, the browsing link only reveals 43. What could be the reason?